# JMeter IF-condition check

Tags: if-statement, jmeter, client-side

In client-side script 1st user creates events in a calendar for 2nd user, 2nd user accepts/declines them.

I would like to exclude possible errors during event creation and check if event request was created before 2nd user tries to accept it using xpath built on event request template like:

EventRequest_SubjectN
(N is iteration number of event request in a cycle, so if event request N wasn't created by 1st user, 2nd user action with event N fails).

Between these actions are another actions of both users, by this reason I can't use ${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}.

Is there any analog of this function, but for necessary/specific action several steps ago, not for last sample?

What is the best way to organize IF-condition is that case?

I think about to add BeanShell PostProcessor after 1st user Event request N with a code like:

var rc = prev.getResponseCode();
if(rc.equals("200")){

vars.put('EventRequest_Subject_${N}', 'EventRequest_Subject_${N}');
}

and use not null condition for EventRequest_Subject_${N} in IF-controller for 2nd user.

But it doesn't work in this way. Where am I wrong?

**UPD. Solution:**

Tried 3 ways:

1. if Event_RequestN created - put into variable specific value, then use it in IF-condition before 2nd user action with Event_RequestN;
2. add action with specific assertion before 2nd user action with Event_RequestN and use ${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok} in IF-condition;
3. add action with xpath extractor before 2nd user action with Event_RequestN and use ${_*isVarDefined(EventRequest_Subject*${N}_FOUND)} in IF-condition;

and ended up with 3rd variant as the best on practice.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't use Beanshell, [since JMeter 3.1 you're supposed to be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting)
2. [Don't inline JMeter Functions or Variables into scripts](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler), go for code-based equivalents instead
3. As per [JMeter Documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)

   > Properties are not the same as variables. Variables are local to a thread; properties are common to all threads

   so if you want to share a piece of data between 2 threads (virtual users) you need to use `props`, not `vars`
4. It's easier to implement your scenario using [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-inter-thread-communication-plugin-in-jmeter)

Comment: Thank you, interesting about Inter-Thread Communication Plugin, but the implementation uses 1 client-side Thread group only (now it works fine in this way). The stack point still is workaround with IF-condition.